# Dialogue consisting of questions and answers?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, archaic-language, literature, word-play

Is there a specific word for a dialogue between two characters in a play or novel, where that dialogue only consists of questions and answers?

Comment: The word *dialogue* already means spoken conversation. Do you mean something specific like question-answer-question-answer? Perhaps *interrogation* or *interrogative dialogue*?

Comment: Perhaps 'argument' ?

Answer (score 1):

[*Stichomythia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stichomythia) is the technical term for an extended dramatic passage in which two characters speak alternating lines of verse. There's also *hemistichomythia*, in which the characters alternate half-lines and *distichomythia*, in which they alternate couplets.

The device was fairly common in classical Greek tragedy, and Renaissance playwrights often adopted it. The term is often extended to rapid-fire alternation in prose, such as Abbot & Costello's famous *Who's on first* routine:

> Abbott: Strange as it may seem, they give ball players nowadays very peculiar names.
>   Costello: Funny names?
>   Abbott: Nicknames, nicknames. Now, on the St. Louis team we have Who's on first, What's on second, I Don't Know is on third—
>   Costello: That's what I want to find out. I want you to tell me the names of the fellows on the St. Louis team.
>   Abbott: I'm telling you. Who's on first, What's on second, I Don't Know is on third--
>   Costello: You know the fellows' names?
>   Abbott: Yes.
>   Costello: Well, then who's playing first?
>   Abbott: Yes.
>   Costello: I mean the fellow's name on first base.
>   Abbott: Who.
>   Costello: The fellow playin' first base.
>   Abbott: Who.
>   Costello: The guy on first base.
>   Abbott: Who is on first.
>   Costello: Well, what are you askin' me for?
>   Abbott: I'm not asking you—I'm telling you. Who is on first.
>   Costello: I'm asking you—who's on first?
>   Abbott: That's the man's name.
>   Costello: That's who's name?
>   Abbott: Yes.

The device is not restricted to Q&A situations, but of course it's admirably suited to them.

Answer (score 0):

There is no non-technical word for this. But the situation can be simply described

> A dialogue where one person asks and the other answers.

A particular scene may describe various types of question-answer dialogues [note how, having established context the phrase "question-answer dialogue" is now clear] for example an "interview" or a "Socratic dialogue". You may find that one of these more precise terms suits your needs better.